# jQuery MouseEnter with Ajax prob?

Tags: ajax, mouseenter

I am having an issue with the following logic - because the ajax request runs multiple times and I only want it to run once ?

```
var currentItem = jQuery('#specialId .myclass');

currentItem.mouseenter(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/url/data",
        data: "myData=" + dataNow,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that I have a bunch of `.myClass` which means that the ajax request runs multiple times. How can I get it run only once when the user enters over the currentItem they are entering ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
currentItem.one("mouseenter", function () {

    // rest of implementation

});
```

...and problem solved.

- http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: hmm thanks for the response. The problem is that this still doesn't work ? I have 4 `class="myclass"` - so it still runs 4x ajax queries ? I only want one ajax query to fire when the user `mouseenter` the `currentItem` they on ?

Comment: @Andy - That should not be the case. The even should fire separately for each individual `.myclass` - or am I missing the point?